# JBDC driver not working as gradle dependency

Tags: java, mysql, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm pretty new to Gradle so excuse my confusion.

I've put the MySQL Java Connector from Maven Repos to my Gradle dependencies inside build.gradle,
but when I try this : Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); I get this exception: /home/charming/Porkramming/javaApps/chatApplication/app/src/main/java/charming/actualCode/App.java

I can run ./gradlew build succesfully, and there's even mysql-connector-8.0.32.jar file in gradle build/lib directory.

I've tried following a lot of tutorials, but most of them resort to manual download and editing classPath through the IDE, which I both don't want to do, and I don't really know how to do since I'm using VSCode as my IDE and i'm not sure where I could configure the java class build path.

Comment: That is not an exception, it is a path to a Java source file. What are the actual code, the actual exception and error message, and the actual gradle configuration?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.